# Is it possible to find a window without supplying the WindowName in DNS Advanced Scripting

Tags: scripting, naturallyspeaking

I am trying to find a specific window-class and want to send a custom message to it via a DNS command. I have trouble locating the window.

This is a working example for Notepad:

```
Declare Function FindWindow Lib "USER32" _
(ByVal lpszClassName As String, ByVal lpszWindow As String) As Long

Sub Main
    Dim hWnd As Long
    hWnd = FindWindow("Notepad", "Unbenannt - Editor") '<-- german title; change it
    Debug.Print CStr(hWnd)
End Sub
```

However, It will not find the handle if I use the following:

```
hWnd = FindWindow("Notepad", vbNullString)
```

And I think it should. Here is the [MSDN-Entry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499(v=vs.85).aspx) for it. It states, that the window name is optionally. Am I missing something?

I think that getting the window name is not an option in my case, as the target is an rich-edit-control which will not have a static window name as it send it's content rather than a static title (which is standard behavior). So I need to get this to work wthout supplying a window name.

Comment: My go to move in these situations is to call an autohotkey script by voice that can do everything you want done.  Try `ShellExecute "commandLine", 6` to do its work in the background.  You can even return info to your running Dragon advanced script (using ClipBoard).

Comment: If you have found an answer, please let us know.

Comment: This problem got obsolete for me. I appreciated your Input @PGilm. I did send unused keycodes to my application like VK_OEM_FJ_MASSHOU, to trigger a certain event which did not require parameters. (A full list of virtual keys is available here: http://www.kbdedit.com/manual/low_level_vk_list.html)